# How to disable changing resolution when monitor turn off?

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics, 4k-resolution

My monitor occasionally 'clicks' and go inaccessible or go in standby mode and go inaccessible (I have to turn it off/turn on). After that Intel HD Graphics drives tries to change resolution to something standard that is far less than native 4K display resolution.
How to disable such behaviour?
Keep in mind that disable screen turn off doesn't help much.

Comment: Sounds like you need to replace your faulty monitor.

Comment: Do you get a notification that tells you your drivers crashed, and recovered? You may want to reinstall your VGA drivers

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Do we rule or what... 2 comments and all possible causes have been mentioned already. xD

Comment: ATI drivers doesn't change resolution until monitor detected. This is fine. No crash in event viewer. 
This problem is not dependent from motherboard because I changed it.

Comment: Problem has solved after reinstalling the system.